# poll() socket programming tcp linux multiple connections issue

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm new to socket programming, but I have followed ibm example at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzab6/poll.htm and changed some code to make it better but when I connect to the server via telnet ip port, and make it echo messages it works for the first client that connects but on second it does not echo the messages?

```
#include <netinet/in.h> // sockaddr_in struct
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr()
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h> //errors
#include <stdio.h> //perror()
#include <cstdlib> //EXIT_FAILURE
#include <sys/ioctl.h> //FIONBIO
#include <unistd.h> //close file descriptor
#include <fcntl.h> //make non blocking
#include <poll.h> //poll stuff
#include <string.h> //memset
int main()
{
    int s = -1;
    int rc;
    int optval = 1;
    int timeout;
    bool end_server = false; //because we need to log if EWOULDBLOCK is true...

    struct pollfd fds[200]; //initialize pollfd struct
    int nfds = 1; // nfds_t really set to 1 else it will be 199 once we pass it to poll....

    int current_size = 0;

    int new_s = -1;

    int close_conn;

    char *buff;

    int len;

    bool compress_array;

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //make socket description reusable with SO_REUSEADDR
    rc = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&optval), sizeof(optval));
    if(rc < 0){
        perror("setsockopt()");
        close(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //make socket non-blocking
    //rc = ioctl(s, FIONBIO, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&optval));
    //if(rc < 0)
    //{
    //    perror("ioctl()");
    //    close(s);
    //    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    //}
    fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    //initialize sockaddr_in struct
    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));

    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    rc = bind(s, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(&saddr), sizeof(saddr));

    if(rc < 0){
        perror("bind()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    rc = listen(s, 32);
    if(rc < 0){
        perror("listen() failed");
        close(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //initialize fds struct
    memset(&fds, 0, sizeof(fds));

    fds[0].fd = s;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN; //check if data to read

    //initialize timeout value to 3 mins based on millisecs
    //timeout = (3 * 60 * 1000); // because function will be like sleep() that uses millisecs
    timeout = 10000;

    do{
        //call poll() and wait 3 mins to complete because of timeout
        printf("Waiting on poll()...\n");
        rc = poll(fds, nfds, timeout);

        if(rc < 0){
            perror("poll() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //check if 3 minutes timeout expired
        if(rc == 0){
            printf("poll() timed out ending program...\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        current_size = nfds;
        for(int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)
        {
            //loop thru fds and check if revents returns POLLIN, means the fd have data to read...
            if(fds[i].revents == 0)
                continue;


            //if revents is not POLLIN then exit program and log
            if(fds[i].revents != POLLIN){
                printf("revents != POLLIN, revents = %d\n", fds[i].revents);
                //end_server = true;
                //break;
                //perror("revents unknown");
                //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                close(fds[i].fd);
                fds[i].fd = -1;
                break;
            }

            if(fds[i].fd == s){
                printf("Listening socket available\n");

                do{
                    //accept each new incoming connections
                    new_s = accept(s, NULL, NULL);
                    if(new_s < 0){
                        if(errno != EWOULDBLOCK){
                            perror("accept() failed because of socket would block");
                            end_server = true;
                        }
                        //printf("something else wrong with accept()\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    //add new incoming connection
                    printf("new incoming connection - nfds: %d\n", new_s);
                    fds[nfds].fd = new_s;
                    fds[nfds].events = POLLIN;
                    nfds++;
                    //continue;
                    //loop back up and accept another connection

                } while(new_s != -1);
            }
            // file descriptor is readable because its now new_s instead of s
            else {
                printf("descriptor %d is readable\n", fds[i].fd);
                close_conn = false;
                //receive all data on this connection till we go back and poll again
                do {

                    rc = recv(fds[i].fd, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&buff), sizeof(buff), 0);
                    if(rc < 0){
                        if(errno != EWOULDBLOCK){
                            perror("recv() failed");
                            close_conn = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    //check if conn was closed by client
                    if(rc == 0){
                        printf("connection closed");
                        close_conn = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    //data was received
                    len = rc;
                    printf("%d bytes received", len);

                    //process stuff or echo data back to client
                    rc = send(fds[i].fd, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&buff), sizeof(buff), 0);
                    if(rc < 0){
                        perror("send() failed");
                        close_conn = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    memset(&buff, 0, sizeof(buff));

                } while (true);
                if(close_conn){
                    close(fds[i].fd);
                    fds[i].fd = -1;
                    compress_array = true;
                }

            }


        }
        if(compress_array){
            compress_array = false;
            int i = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < nfds; i++){
                if(fds[i].fd == -1){
                    for(int j = i; j < nfds; j++){
                        fds[j].fd = fds[j+1].fd;
                    }
                    i--;
                    nfds--;
                }
            }
        }

    } while (end_server == false);

    //clean all sockets that are open
    for(int i = 0; i < nfds; i++){
        if(fds[i].fd > 0){ // if already -1 don't need to close socket
            close(fds[i].fd);
            fds[i].fd = -1;
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but it works if I disconnect first client and try send on other one ?

Comment: found what was causing it it's because I added break; after  printf("something else wrong with accept()\n"); but now when I connect to the first client send msg it echo back but when I connect to the second client and send msg and disconnect from first one it only sends echo back when first disconnects? how to make it so it sends at same time instead of queue ?

Comment: I know the queue is because of rc = listen(s, 32); but how to make it non blocking ?

Comment: Also fixed bug of if(fds[i].revents != POLLIN){ so I break instead of exiting, but it still queue the msgs ?

Comment: or its because poll() is like blocking but queue msgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh it was because I looped with while(true) so it kept looping trying to recv data instead of going back up and add new connection to the list.